# A and X keys not working all the time on Acer Aspire E laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, keyboard, acer-aspire

So I've been having this annoying issue for a few days now.

I sometimes have to hold one of them, and they slowly get typed in the textbox in which i'm typing, and gradually get more cursive to the point where it actually seems to work as it should, but between 1 and 10 minutes later it fails again.

I tried restarting from the start menu, didn't change much although it seemed to have worked better at first, so I'm thinking it might not be physical damage after all. And besides use over the past year there's not much that could cause it.

I then found a forum post telling me to turn it off from the button, taking out the battery and letting it stay. I did that and I let it stay while I cooked some food.

Didn't change anything, I was barely able to type my password.

An interesting thing is that, when one of them comes back they both come back. And doing the previously mentioned thing usually makes both of them come back too, so it's certainly not just the keys themselves, it's probably either some driver issue or some other part of the keyboard.

I'm using Windows 10 Home, I just checked, it's up to date. I remember it updated a few days ago.

I went into Device Manager and checked the keyboard driver, it tells me it's up to date although it's from 2006 apparently, but I mean, I suppose there's not much you can add to a keyboard driver so whatever. I wanted to disable it and enable it thinking it might help but the disable button is ironically disabled itself and I can't click it. Only the uninstall button seems to work and I wasn't planning on clicking it.

I have no usb keyboard, and I'm an indie game developer so I'm having a really bad time right now trying to program.

I also removed the keycaps and cleaned them, which had no effect whatsoever.
I don't have any knowledge about the types of laptop keyboards, but I noticed there's an... elevation made of what seems to be silicone rubber with a white plastic square over.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked for a virus?

Comment: Well, I haven't installed anything for months, and certainly not any random stuff. And Windows Defender says everything's alright.

Comment: I wouldn't think it was a virus... boot up to a usb or CD to rule out windows or virus or some setting... I would imagine it was physical.

so try any USB or CD... I'd google "Gandalf winpe iso" and put that on a CD or USB and use that for a bit to rule out anything in your installation... or just use your original windows whatever CD and press CTRL-F10 or use command prompt.